# HQ camera hanging after gpu_mem is increased

Tags: python, raspicam, picamera, gpu, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I just recently got a Raspberry Pi HQ camera and wanted to operate it using a python script.
I initially tried to take full resolution pictures using the default gpu_mem=128, but the program crashed saying `picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: unable to enable port vc.ril.camera.out:2: Out of memory`.
Setting the resolution to lower values worked and the pictures were taken without any issues.  I then tried to change the gpu_mem to 256 MB as to give the camera enough space for full pictures.
When I rebooted the pi, however, and ran the script using full resolution, the camera hung and got stuck during the capture process. `raspistill` however still works normally (as long as it's run before the script, which hangs and makes the camera inaccessible).
This is the relevant code:

```
def takeimg(params):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        setup(camera, params)
        sleep(2)
        image = np.empty((params.camera.xres * params.camera.yres * 3,), dtype=np.uint8)
        camera.capture(image, 'bgr')
        image = image.reshape((params.camera.yres, params.camera.xres, 3))
        return image
```

`params` is a namedtuple containing some parameters used to set the camera.

I have tried different gpu_mem sizes but nothing above 128 MB seems to work consistently

#### Info:

- picamera module, version 1.13
- Rasperry Pi 3B+
- HQ Camera V1.0 2018
- Raspi OS Lite 32 bit Bullseye (latest version)

Any tips on how to take the pictures at full resolution? I'm really stuck at the moment

## Edit:

I've done some testing and have narrowed down the issue by comparing these two scripts:

#### Script 1:

```
import picamera
import numpy as np
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (4032, 3040)
    img = np.empty((4032*3040*3), dtype=np.uint8)
    camera.capture(img, "bgr")
    img = img.reshape((3040, 4032, 3))
```

#### Script 2:

```
import picamera
import numpy as np
with picamera.PiCamera() as cam:
    cam.resolution = (4032, 3040)
    cam.capture("picture.jpg")
```

While the second script runs without any issues, the first script gets stuck at the `camera.capture('img', 'bgr')`, which means that (probably due to some gpu_mem issues) the camera isn't able to write to the numpy stream and remains stuck there instead.